# Scrapy - Database choice

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch, scrapy, nosql

I'm currently building a scrapy project that can crawl any website from the first depth to the last. I don't extract many data, but I store the all page HTML (`response.body`) in a database.

I am currently using **Elasticsearch** with the **bulk API**, to store my raw HTML.

I had a look in **Cassandra** but I did not find an equivalent of the **Elasticsearch bulk** and it affects the performances of my spider.

I am interested in performance, and was wondering if Elasticsearch was a good choice, and if maybe there was a more appropriate **NoSQL database**.

Comment: Couldn't you just store them on the local disk?

Comment: I can't because my spider runs in a cloud environnement and I need to get that data from another VM later for analysis

Comment: An other option is to compress them (either one-by-one or in chunks) and store to S3 or any other such service. It is trivial to setup when compared to a full-fledged database.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have a look !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That very much depends on what you are planning to do with the scraped data later on.

Elasticsearch does some complex indexing operations upon insertion which will make subsequent searches in the database quite fast ... but this also costs processing time and introduces a latency.

So to answer your question whether Elasticsearch was a good choice:

If you plan to build some kind of search engine later on, Elasticsearch was a good choice (as the name indicates). But you should have a close look at the configuration of Elasticsearch's indexing options etc to make sure it works the way you need it.

If on the other hand you just want to store the data and do processing tasks on it later, Elasticsearch was a poor choice and you would be better off with Cassandra or another NoSQL database.

Which NoSQL database suits your needs best, depends - again - on the actual usage scenario.

Comment: Actually I built my Elasticsearch's mapping on 'not analyzed' so the ES engine does not make unnecessary things. The problem I have with Cassandra is that I have to insert my pages one by one, I can't make a bulk insert, and the performances are not as good as ES'.

Comment: Ok, then the additional processing cost will be somewhat lower, but still higher than for a "normal" database. So most probably Elasticsearch was a not so good choice.